# how to expand this expression using series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How does $$(R^2 +[|x|]^2)^{0.5}$$ expand as $$R + \frac{[|x|]^2}{2R} + \text{(more terms)}$$ around the point $x  = 0$? I tried using a Taylor series but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write $\sqrt{R^2+x^2}=R\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{R^2}}$. Then you can expand $\sqrt{1+u}$ with $u=\frac{x^2}{R^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x$ is real, and $0<R$, the Absolute value doesn't buy you anything and you have:

$$R+\frac{x^2}{2 R}-\frac{x^4}{8 R^3} +\frac{x^6}{16 R^5}-\frac{5 x^8}{128 R^7}$$

Answer (score 0):

Factor out $R^2$ and use Newton's binomial series.